# Define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have included the following code at the begining of main.cpp file (the file that houses main function) but I am still getting the bellow mentioned warning.

Code:

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN64
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10
#elif _WIN32
#error "Build only supports x86-64 and not does not supports x86"
#endif // _Win64
```

Warning:

```
Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to the compiler command line; or
add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 (i.e. Windows 7 target).
```

Comment: Are you sure it's defined before `windows.h` is included?

Comment: Yes, this is the first line of the program.

Comment: There may be a precompiled header with `#include "Windows.h"` in it.

Comment: I have set the option Precompiled Headers to Not Using Precompiled Headers.
No precomipled header file is present in the code.

Comment: @DarkSorrow did you try doing what the warning says and put the value in your project makefile/settings instead? It shouldn't be set in your code

Comment: @RemyLebeau Added it in Preprocessor Definitions solved the warning but I am trying to understand why I am getting this error in my current project while the same code is working in my other projects. The build environment hasn't changed hence this should not be an issue.

Comment: Also check for `/FI` in compiler's command line

Comment: This warning comes from Boost, [config.hpp header file](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp).  How Boost is related to the code snippet is not obvious.

Comment: @HansPassant Boost could be a possible cause as Boost.Asio is being used in my current project which was not used in other projects. Can you explain why even after defining `#define _WIN32_WINDOWS _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10`  at the beginning of the maon.cpp file the compiler was giving that warning.